# Scichart can't remove annotation

Tags: android, scichart

When Im trying to remove an annotation, I’m receiving an error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   ‘void
>   com.scichart.charting.visuals.annotations.IAnnotationPlacementStrategy.drawAdorner(android.graphics.Canvas)’
>   on a null object reference at
>   com.scichart.charting.visuals.annotations.AnnotationBase.onDrawAdorner(SourceFile:889)
>   at
>   com.scichart.charting.visuals.annotations.AdornerLayer.onDraw(SourceFile:144)
>   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17071) at
>   android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16053)

I’ve tried many ways, like:

```
UpdateSuspender.using(priceChart, new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        priceChart.getAnnotations().clear();
    }
});
```

and

```
UpdateSuspender.using(priceChart, new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        priceChart.getAnnotations().remove(myAnnotation);
    }
});
```

But I just can't remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the official answer from Scichart team:

> Hi Marcos,
>
> I want to notify you that I’ve investigated and fixed this issue. It
>   was caused by a small bug in our code – when you remove annotation
>   from chart it doesn’t remove adorner for annotation if it is selected.
>   The fix will be available in our next nightly build and for now you
>   can workaround this issue by unselecting annotation before removing
>   from collection:

```
UpdateSuspender.using(priceChart, new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        myAnnotation.setSelected(false);
        priceChart.getAnnotations().remove(myAnnotation);
    }
});
```

> Hope this will help you!
>
> Best regards,
>   Yura

Answer (score 0):

That's weird. There's a [SciChart Android Tutorial on Annotations here](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/android/v2.x/Tutorial%2007%20-%20Adding%20Annotations.html). It uses 'chart.getAnnotations().remove(0)'

The full source code for this tutorial can be found at the [SciChart.Android.Examples Github repository](https://github.com/ABTSoftware/SciChart.Android.Examples/tree/master/v2.x/Tutorials/SciChartAndroid_Tutorial7).

Does it work for you?